# Webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem here where when I reserved book from this date (for example 09/07/2013 as the date reserved and 09/11/2013 as the expiration date). To check if it is forfeited I logout then change my calendar date to 09/11/2013, then when I refresh the login.form it says webpage has a redirect loop.

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller{

function index()
{
    $this->load->model('admin/confirmation_model');
    $data['confirmation'] = $this->confirmation_model->getConfirm();
    $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

}
//added function update
function update($isbn){
    $statuses = 'Forfeited';
    $data = array(
        'status' => $statuses
    );

    $this->db->where('isbn',$isbn);
    $this->db->update('reserved_dummy',$data);

    $sql = 'update books set stock=stock+1 where isbn=?';
    $this->db->query($sql, $isbn);
    redirect('login');
}
```

this is my view:

```
<?php $date = date('m/d/Y'); 
      $tomorrow = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($date)); 
      if ($confirmation) { 
        foreach($confirmation as $r) { 
           if (date('m/d/Y',strtotime($r->date_expire . "+1 days")) == $tomorrow && $r->status != 'forfeited') { 
              redirect('login/update/'.$r->isbn,'location'); 
           } 
         } 
      } 
?>
```

Comment: this is my view                                                          <?php
 
 $date = date('m/d/Y');
 $tomorrow = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($date));
  if($confirmation){
  foreach($confirmation as $r){
if(date('m/d/Y',strtotime($r->date_expire . "+1 days")) == $tomorrow && $r->status != 'forfeited'){
redirect('login/update/'.$r->isbn,'location');
   }
  }
 }
 ?>

Comment: it is already edited above

Comment: Great. ^ It's common practice here to remove old comments too, just so you know.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CI, but if the "view" is just a templating engine, I'd say it is the wrong place to do a `redirect` - I would tend towards putting that in the controller. However, that doesn't help with the immediate problem - for that, remove the `redirect` and swap it with `echo/exit`, so you can look at `$r->date_expire`. Ah, and `$tomorrow` looks wrong - that looks like today.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue may be related to your use of "American" style dates (m/d/Y). This is a very ambiguous format for computers. Try the following and see what happens.

Change all `date('m/d/Y')` to `date('Y-m-d')`.

The reason why; because when you pass `'09/08/2013'` to `strtotime()`, a 'guess' is made by PHP. The reason for the guess? Almost only Americans read their dates in `m/d/Y` format. For example, I read this date as *9th of Aug, 2013*, but Americans would say it was the *8th of Sept, 2013*.

If you pass `'2013-09-08'` to `strtotime()` there is no confusion as this is always interpreted as 'Y-m-d' format.

Comment: I guess it depends on how the CI ORM works - some of them work with database-style dates, some work with localised ones.